# Input inside topbar in Zurb Foundation goes up while width decreaze

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have an example
        [http://jsfiddle.net/YEBe8/]
When I resize window with result (descrease width) - I see that my unput box goes to upper fridge of top bar, how to avoid it?

Comment: Hey user2572790, I took a look at your jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/YEBe8/](http://jsfiddle.net/YEBe8/) and it looks like your missing some HTML code to make a proper top-bar. You are also missing the actual `foundation.min.css` and `foundation.min.js` needed for the top-bar to display correctly. If you can set the jsfiddle up with your actual code I will gladly take another look. Here is a great reference to get you started http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

your html is not valid. You have to close your input width `/>` and you can not place a `input` as direct child elment of an `<ul>` add a `<li>`. 
If your content is cropped it's likely you did not add:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns large-12">
        <input type="text" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All that's right, but problem still actual, And it's good visible at exampe: while resizing window input button pressed to the upper edge of black top bar